# What are the largest and smallest values that can be stored in an SPFieldDateTime?

Tags: visual-studio, object-model, spfield

What it says on the tin, basically! I assumed it's the same as a regular .NET DateTime struct, but whenever I try to store 01-Jan-0001 (smallest DateTime value), I get an error. Can't find it on MSDN or Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimum value is 1/1/1900.  We have run into the minimum value issue with trying to date some documents from the 1800's. - [Stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925626/sharepoint-date-and-time-field-limitation)